# How to keep autoresize textarea text away from the very bottom of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autosize

I'm trying to create a 100px gap between a textarea that autoresizes using this js library [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) and the very bottom of the screen.

The demo from the link showcases this problem. Once you hit the bottom of the screen there is no space between the text and the window.

Cant seem to find any solutions and margins and paddings dont seem to fix this. Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: you could add a listener for the `autosize:resized` event on the textarea, then scroll down 100px every time the textarea resizes and the new height pushes the bottom of the textarea out of the visible window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***An important note*** is that, in order to work, the script below needs *flow-content* after the `<textarea>` element worth of `100px` in `height`. If it doesn't have it, it can't `scroll` there, so it doesn't work. I provided this scroll-space by setting a `padding-bottom:100px` on `<body>` but if you have enough content after your `<textarea>` to provide the `100px` of scroll space, that padding is not necessary. Actually, all of the `CSS` is there mostly to demonstrate the principle, you shouldn't add it to your project.

The solution is provided by the `javascript` part.

***Another note*** would be that this is not a *fully-working-fit-all-copy-paste-ultimate-solution*, but rather a *delicate-proof-of-concept*. It's up to you to understand what it does and alter it so it works for your specific case. If you have any trouble applying it, just ask/provide details.

And, as ***a final note***, I only added `jQuery` to it after trying to get `scrollTo` animated in vanilla without much success. In the end I didn't want to lose more time so just used `jQuery.animate()`. If you don't need to smooth-scroll to position or if you know how to do it in vanilla, `jQuery` should be removed altogether (as autosizer is stand-alone too). So, if you need/want it, I could provide a `jQuery` free non-animated solution.

Here it is:

```js
autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'));

$('textarea').each(function(){
  autosize(this);
}).on('autosize:resized', function(){
  let fromBottom = $(window).height() - this.clientHeight;
  if (fromBottom < 102) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop:(102 - fromBottom) + 'px'
    }, 210);
  }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
body {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
body::before {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autosize.js/3.0.20/autosize.min.js"></script>


<textarea>test textarea</textarea>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. I should have put up a snippet you're right. I managed to get the scroll working too ( also thanks shamsup) although your solution is better. I've been trying to figure out how to fix the issue of stopping the scroll from moving if I happen to go back up for example and edit/ add more text in the middle. Using getBoundingClientRect(). Not sure if you could point me in the right direction? Thanks anyway

Comment: I can tell you from experience that, given the different ways each browser scrolls the focus into view internally, you're about to make that `textarea` unusable on quite a few devices and not even know about it. My personal advice is not to go down this road at all (not for some extra `padding`, anyway). But, if you need the extra challenge, factor in `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;` to the formula. It's the position of the focus (cursor) in the textarea.

Comment: Yeh I think I may have too, its not completely essential (just looks better!) thank you for your suggestions and help.

Comment: @user3752958: Glad to help and enjoyed the challenge. You're welcome (to [so]). Happy coding! : }<(((*> ::)